# SQLite Inserts - How to Insert Any Text while Avoiding Syntax Errors using Parameterized Values

Tags: sql, vb.net, sqlite

I'm curious to know a proper way to insert text strings into a database regardless of what characters are contained within the string. What I'm getting at is if I have a string for example that contains single quotes or any other character that is reserved as a 'special' SQL character.

The issue specifically that I'm dealing with is that I don't have control over the possible 'Text' that is being inserted into my database as the text is generated by my application.

One example of where my application fails to insert properly is when there's an error message that happens to contain single quotes.  Single quotes are used by SQL statements insert text of course and so I can't insert text that also contains single quotes (outside of using ascii value char(##) function).  The issue I'm dealing with is that I'm setting the output of my application to a string variable to then be inserted into my database so I can log activity whether that be standard output or catching errors.

How do I simply INSERT what's contained in my string variable while avoiding all of the SQL Special characters?

Do I need to manually account for all of the SQL Special characters and replace them in my string prior to insert?  This sounds like a hit or miss and I'm hoping that there's something already built to accommodate this situation.

Sample Pseudo Code to get the point across:

Let's say an error occurred within the app and it needs to be logged. The error string could be:

> Error String: "Error in function calculateStats() parameter 'pBoolStatCheck' is Null"

Now I assign to my string variable within my app and build up the SQL Insert string.

```
var insertString = "Error in function calculateStats() parameter 'pBoolStatCheck' is Null"


INSERT INTO outputLog(outputLogText) 
VALUES ('insertString');   --This will Fail

--Fails due to the variable 'insertString' containing single quotes.
INSERT INTO outputLog(outputLogText) 
VALUES ('Error in function calculateStats() parameter 'pBoolStatCheck' is Null');
```

In closing - since I have no control over the text that could be created by my application how do I account for all of the possible characters that could break my insert?

The code my current application encountering this issue is written in Visual Basic. The database I'm working with is SQLite.

The final solution based on answers received by this post:

```
Public Sub saveOutputLog(pTextOutput, pTextColor, pNumNewLines, plogType, pMethodSub)

    Dim strTableName As String = "outputLog"
    Dim sqlInsert As String = "INSERT INTO " & strTableName & "(" &
                              "outputLog, logColor, numNewLines, logType, method" &
                              ") VALUES (@outputLog, @logColor, @numNewLines, @logType, @method);"

    Try
        'Open the Database
        outputLogDBConn.Open()

        'Create/Use a command object via the connection object to insert data into the outputLog table
        Using cmd = outputLogDBConn.CreateCommand() 
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
            cmd.CommandText = sqlInsert
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@outputLog", pTextOutput)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@logColor", pTextColor)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@numNewLines", pNumNewLines)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@logType", plogType)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@method", pMethodSub)

            'Execute the command using above Insert and added Parameters.
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

        End Using 'Using outputLogDBComm

        outputLogDBConn.Close()

    Catch ex As Exception

        outputLogDBConn.Close()

    End Try

End Sub
```

Comment: You would use parameterized queries to bind the String at runtime. This will also prevent you from having SQL Injection vulnerabilities. It would help if I knew what language you are working in so I can point you in the right direction.

Comment: @user2827048 The code my current application encountering this issue is written in Visual Basic.  The database I'm working with is SQLite.  I also updated the original post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem is very similar to the problem of preventing SQL Injection vulnerabilities in your code. Queries are very easy to break, and while yours breaks in a way that is harmless and annoying, these can be taken to levels where certain inputs can completely destroy your database!

One of the best ways to approach this is by using parameterized queries. This approach is pretty simple; you write the query first with 'placeholders' for the parameters you will send. Once you are ready in your program you can then 'bind' those parameters to the placeholders.

It would look something like the following:

```
Dim command = New SqlCommand("INSERT INTO outputLog(outputLogText) VALUES  (@stringToInsert)", connection);
.
.
.
code
.
.
.
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@stringToInsert", errorMessage)
.
.
.
execute query
```

In the above you see that `@stringToInsert` is the placeholder which is only bound at a later time. It doesn't matter what the variable `errorMessage` contains, since it will not cause the query to function in a way where the input causes it to potentially break.

There are a lot of resources on this:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.prepare?view=netframework-4.7.2

Answer (score 1):

Database objects like connections not only need to be closed but also disposed. A Using block will ensure this will happen even if there is an error.

The `.Add` is better than `.AddWithValue` for a number of reasons. See https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/  and http://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/
The parameters of `.Add` are the name of the parameter, the datatype in the database and optionally the size of the field. You will need to check the database for the last 2.

Open the connection at the last minute befor the execute.

If you are using OleDb with Access, you need to make sure the parameters are added in the same order as they appear in the sql statement.

```
    Using cn As New SqlConnection("Your connection string")
        Using cmd As New SqlCommand("INSERT INTO outputLog(outputLogText) VALUES (@outputLogText);", cn)
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@outputLogText", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = TextBox1.Text
            cn.Open()
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        End Using
    End Using
```